# How to create inputs for a pytorch seperable conv model?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I want to create a pytorch model that takes input of medical images. The images are of shape height = 91, width = 91, slices = 7 and channels = 1.

I created a 2D separable conv using the following conv layer

```
nn.Sequential(
nn.Conv2D(in_c, in_c, groups = in_c)
nn.Conv2D(in_c, out_c, kernel_size = 1)
)
```

when I try to create a random tensor for shape (64, 7, 1, 91, 91) using torch.rand(64, 7, 1, 91,91 ). Where 64 is batch size, 7 is number of slices, 1 is channel and 91 are height and width I get an error. Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [1, 1, 5, 5] but got 5-dimensional input size [64, 7, 1, 91, 91] instead.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: You either need to change to Conv3D or remove the channel dimension (64, 7, 91, 91).

Comment: So, this is the first solution that I thought of that Either I change the image to (64, 7, 91, 91) and other is is also the same that I change it to Conv3D. I have a question that if I change it to (64, 7, 91, 91) then will I lose any channel information or not ?